# How to change file back to beginning - git

Tags: git, github

I have been committing for awhile now and I realized there is one file that I want changed in all commits back to initial. What is the easiest way to overwrite one file with another through all past commits?

Comment: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git reset $initialcommit -- $path_to_file -- --all`

Answer (score 0):

To confirm- what you want is that all the files in the repositories remain untouched except one which will be changed over all the commits:

Here's a clean and simple way:
Create a file that has contents exactly how you want. Put it in a directory outside of the repository.

Run the following command:
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp  ' HEAD

Note that this will change the commit hash of all the commits (because the file contents change) . You may want to create a separate branch using `git checkout -b <new branch>` before starting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to checkout the original version of a file, simply type this:

```
git checkout HEAD filename
```

If you know the specific version hash you want, you can also do this:

```
git checkout 653e0c0 filename
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [`git-log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and [`git-checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) should do the trick. Try this:

```
$ git checkout `git log --pretty="format:%h" your_file | tail -1` -- your_file
```

Now to dissect what that means:

1. `git log --pretty="format:%h" your_file` will return all the logs history of `your_file`. We use the `--pretty="format:%h"` flag to limit the output to just the commits sha. If you ran this command alone, you will see it returns a list of commits which made up the history of your file. (Remove `--pretty="format:%h"` to see the full logs)
2. Then we have to do the silly piping `| tail -1` to pick up the last commit in the list from the previous `git-log` command. This last commit will corresponds to the first-ever commit which your file is apart of. We have to do the piping because `git log --reverse -1` performs the filtering of the commits first (i.e. the `-1` flag), before re-ordering the result (i.e. the `--reverse` flag). Hence, the result of `git log --reverse -1` is that the most-recent commit associated with your file is returned, instead of the earliest initial commit.
3. Then we rewind your file back to this first-ever commit by using the `git checkout <first_ever_commit_sha> your_file` command.